# Error in Create Stored Procedure SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I tring to create a stored procedure to do Backup in SQL Server Express, and i received this message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'BACKUP'. Expecting '(' or SELECT

This is my code:

```
USE [xxxxdb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE xxxx 
AS
(BACKUP DATABASE xxxdb TO DISK='D:\BackUPs\xxxx.bak' with init,stats=10);
GO
GO
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the unecessary parenthesis

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xxxx 
AS
BACKUP DATABASE xxxdb TO DISK='D:\BackUPs\xxxx.bak' with init,stats=10;
```